# How to capture search params in react when I search with form action="/search"?

Tags: reactjs, search, react-router-dom

I have a form which puts to URL "/search/?q=my searching query..".
How to get this my searching query.. as params?
[image: This route is considered..]

[image: This is my form..]

[image: This what I get in my URL][image]

How to get the my "searching query.." as params? When I try by useParams it doesnt work because of "?" symbol.

Of course I can do it without that action="/search/" on my input but I see it more true way to do searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined ":query" as url parameter, but "?q=my searching query.." is a search query.
You could get it like:

```
const { search } = useLocation();
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
const searchQuery = searchParams.get('q')
```

And you could also remove the ":query" from route path.

Comment: new URLSearchParams(search) - that's what I was looking for. Thanks!